# How do I create an element bigger than my body

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an table, which has to be larger than the body and centered on it. Let me explain a bit more.

Here is my simplified HTML code :

```
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div>
            <table></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My table is initially empty. I fill it with JS code, but I think it doesn't matter for my problem. After the filling, the table is meant to be wider and taller than the body and I want it centered on the body. It means that I want a part of the table out of the screen on each side of it.

At first, I thought I could use

```
#one {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

but the problem is that, okay the table is centered on the body, but it can't be wider than 50% of the body (no problem for the height).

I tried few other things, but I always have an issue with the width of the table which can't be bigger than the width of my window. I don't know what to do. Ask me if you need more information on my code or my goal.

Comment: If you add `width:110%` to the `#one` CSS it should work. Of course since it's larger than body, you will see scrollbars

Comment: It kinda works, but it still shrink my table. It is wider than 110% of the body

Comment: My 110% was an example, you can change it as you need it. Either in % or px

Comment: Do you mean it is wider than the body or it is wider than the viewport?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato An element cant be larger then the body. The body is the container for all visual content. and as such will always automatically resize to fit the content. What you proberly mean is an overflow of the viewport.

Comment: Yup, thanks for sharing the correct way to express that @tacoshy, you're 100% right

Answer (score 0):

@tacoshy comment is an important clarification about the  element. Be sure to understand it.

Three points about what you want to achieve:

1 - When you use % on height and width you are using a percentage relative to the parent element. So To have it bigger than your view, using number higher than 100% could do the trick.

```
#one {
    width: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

2 - But the option above would make the size always relative to the parent element Maybe you want to avoid it hooking the #one size to the viewport, and not to the parent element. For example:

```
#one {
    width: 150vw; // 150 * view width
    height: 150vh; // 150 * view height
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

3 - Maybe it could be a good idea in your case to set aminimux width, this way you are ensuring that the content will never be smaller than yhe value set.

For example:

```
#one {
    min-width: 150vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can use both *width* and *min-width* if you want to refine it or create a more responsive pattern.

Finally, I'd also add an overflow attribute, just be sure that you'd always have your scrolling enabled.

So, this could be my css:

```
#one {
    min-width: 150vw;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```